# Convert list of elements into list of tuples to match the structure of another list of tuples

Tags: python

Say that I have the following lists

```
L = [("a0","a1"),("b0",),("b1","a1","b0"),("a0","a1"),("b0",)]
M = ["u0", "u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5", "u6", "u7" , "u8"]
```

and I want to group the elements of `M` into a list of tuples `N` such that `N` has the same structure of `L`, i.e.

```
N = [("u0", "u1"), ("u2",), ("u3", "u4", "u5"), ("u6", "u7") , ("u8",)]
```

or, to be more precise, such that `[len(L[ii]) == len(N[ii]) for ii, t in enumerate(L)]` has all `True` elements and `M == Q`, where `Q = [item for t in N for item in t]`

How to do that?

Answer (score 8):

```
it = iter(M)
```

followed by

```
res = [tuple(itertools.islice(it, len(t))) for t in L]
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

using for loop

```
>>> L = [("a0","a1"),("b0",),("b1","a1","b0"),("a0","a1"),("b0",)]
>>> M = ["u0", "u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5", "u6", "u7" , "u8"]
>>> R =[]
>>> idx = 0
>>> for i in [len(j) for j in L]:
...     R.append(tuple(M[idx:idx+i]))
...     idx+=i
... 
>>> R
[('u0', 'u1'), ('u2',), ('u3', 'u4', 'u5'), ('u6', 'u7'), ('u8',)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that the good thing of this solution is that it is package independent (the other depends on itertools).

Comment: yeah it is good for people to understand what is happening, itertools solution is also good, but only fesiable when you are using generators and not raw list

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [("a0","a1"),("b0",),("b1","a1","b0"),("a0","a1"),("b0",)]
M = ["u0", "u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5", "u6", "u7" , "u8"]

len_L_elements = []

for i in L:
    len_L_elements.append(len(i))
    
print(len_L_elements)

res = []
c = 0 # It will handle element of M
d = 0 # It will handle element of len_L_elemenst

while c <= len(M)-1 and d <= len(len_L_elements)-1:
    temp_lis = [] # this will convert int tuple on time of append
    cnt = 0 # Initialize with 0 on one tuple creation
    while cnt <= len_L_elements[d]-1:
        temp_lis.append(M[c])
        c+=1
        cnt+=1
    
    # Convert List into tuple
    temp_tuple = tuple(temp_lis)
    res.append(temp_tuple)
    d+=1
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, but have you read the other replies before answering? They are way less verbose than yours. But thank you anyway.